# R: update column-name range in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there an elegant way to update a range of columns selected by names from a data.table?

For example, let's say we have

```
dt <- data.table(A = LETTERS[1:5], B = LETTERS[6:10], C = LETTERS[11:15])
```

I would like to add quotes to all columns from A to B using the `function(x) paste0('"', x, '"')`.

I tried:

```
dt[, .SD := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0('"', x, '"')), .SDcols=A:B]
```

Without result.

Comment: Would `cols <- c("A", "B") ; dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, dQuote), .SDcols = cols]` work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The OP's question is that he doesn't want to create the names manually

Comment: @DavidArenburg as a side note, I used dQuote instead of paste0 to add quotes to several columns and saved to a csv file. I notice that the file size is almost  twice as big when using dQuote. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `names` or even have something like `c("A", "B")`

```
f1 <- function(dat, v1) Reduce(seq, which(colnames(dat) %in% v1))
i1 <- f1(dt, c('A', 'B'))
dt[, (i1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0('"', x, '"')), .SDcols=A:B]
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't necessarily have the location of the columns and also I cannot list them manually because I may have hundreds of them.

Comment: @mat but how do you know that it in the range from `A:B`?  If the columns are random, the only way is to do this manually in case you don't have any patterns.

Comment: They're not in random order. The only thing I know is that somewhere in my data.table there are 4 consecutive columns named "A", "B", "C", "D".

Comment: thank you for your reply, but even if it works it is not what I am looking for, I would really like to find an elegant (simple) solution. I have to repeat this operation several times.

Comment: @mat You can create a function to do that

Comment: Of course I could, but I am convinced that there must be an easier, one sentence approach. I'll wait a bit more to see if someone comes up with a new solution.

Comment: Note that there's no need to create a new function, instead we could just use: `select_vars(names(dt), A:B)` (from `dplyr`). Even though this isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @mat if you are going to load a new package, `dplyr`, yes, that can be used.  If you don't need a function, that is your call.